# Notification shows android icon instead of app icon when app is inactive

Tags: java, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I followed the default firebase guide for setting up android push notifications, but the notification shows android icon when the app is inactive in api 26, when active it shows the app icon, also no notification is shown in redmi note 4 device.

Using this guide converted to kotlin :https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: So you've specified a `default_notification_icon` in your manifest?

Comment: Yes i have added that in manifest